# Net Tcp Binding giving an error in .Net 4.0 when hosted in IIS .TCP error code 10061

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

I am using .net 4.0.

1.I hosted the net tcp binding service on port number 808.
Then I got the error saying as TCP error code 10061.

Then I took care of the following:

1.After going to services.msc I made the "Net Tcp Port sharing service" as automatic.

2.Right clicked on the Web Site and added both "http and net.tcp"
to enable the tcp binding also.

3.Then I ran the following command:

%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set site "Default Web Site" - +bindings.[protocol='net.tcp',bindingInformation='808:*']

But when I used the netsat I found that 808 port is not listening at all.
And I get the Tcp error code 10061.

What could be the reason ?

Only thing I missed was:
In control panel under .net 3.0 there is an option to check both http and non http bindings.

I Ignored it because I am using .Net 4.0. Is this the reason ?Or is there any other settings missing.

Please let me know

Comment: Check your firewall.  it might be blocking that traffic

Comment: I've worked a lot with WCF and the majority of "unexplained" errors are easily diagnosed using tracing.  Review this article and setup Trace. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: I forgot to mention that,I have even disabled the firewall.Only thing I missed was: In control panel under .net 3.0 there is an option to check both http and non http bindings.

I Ignored it because I am using .Net 4.0. Is this the only reason then?

Comment: This is the entire message I get,"TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. " after tracing it.

Comment: There is a lot of information here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=WCF+TCP+10061&submit=search